# Is the battlestar's name located on both sides (port and starboard) of the ship?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Is the name of a battlestar located on both sides of the ship? I recall on the original series they only show the port side of the ship. Is the Galactica's name on the starboard flight deck? I am not sure about Ronald Moore's re-imaged version.

Answer (score 3):

[image]I just re-watched part of the original series (1978) and in the attack on the Colonial Fleet showed vipers on the Galactica launching. An above shot shows them exiting the starboard flight pod with the ships name on it in the same position as on the port side. Guess one of the few camera shots that show it.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot to back this up?

Answer (score 1):

**It would make sense...**

...but what's even stranger, is sometimes the name isn't even on the port side!

[In this clip, for example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RShAMFvnFM): at about 00:09, there doesn't appear to be a name on the port side warp nacelle; yet at about 00:35, the Cylons can see "ATLANTIA" clear as day! Also very clear at 01:27.  Note the narrow strip with 7 "rivets" just above the name. Back at 00:09, the space below that strip is very clearly blank.

[Another example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzyHxYxc-Mo): here at about 02:11 we see the Battlestar NONAME, whereas back at 00:11 "GALACTICA" is visible.

As Valorum notes, BSG was not a high budget endeavour. Lots of recycled footage (worse than SW!) and generic shots. Nevertheless. In all the clips I reviewed, I don't even recall seeing the starboard side of any Battlestar, or any other ship for that matter. Almost all the space battle scenes are shot coming in from the starboard side.

Comment: There were multiple filming miniatures. Also they sometimes used reversed shots to save money.

Comment: Yep. That's pretty clear! That shot of one of the boys trouncing a Cylon ship when it's right on top of the Battlestar is the same footage from the time they thwarted the Cylon attack. Not much thwarting in this episode!

Comment: The restored miniature has the name on both sides; https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO7pZ.jpg / http://www.modelermagic.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/kg-tos_battlestar-studio_model_reference-098.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Instant nostalgia followed by melancholia.

Comment: I'd have posted this as an answer, but I don't know what the "restoration work" refers to. For example, were the names added?

Comment: I really enjoyed that show as well as the remade series. That universe/general storyline always fascinated me, even with the 70s version’s campiness towards its end and.....gulp (Galactica 1985)........and the remade series’ nice but sometimes very dark tendencies. Still the whole concept was thrilling. It was different IMO from the usual “established civilization in a galaxy either exploring or at constant war” concept instead taking up a “last of our kind trying to survive and find a home while products of our arrogance are trying to kill us” mantra.